# WooCommerce add customs notice below checkout email field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to add custom text notice below the email field in the checkout page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, below code should do it.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'so_27270883_woocommerce_form_field', 10, 2 );

function so_27270883_woocommerce_form_field( $field, $key) {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
        if ($key == 'billing_email') {
            $field .= '<p class="form-row">CUSTOM TEXT HERE</p>';
        }
    }
    return $field;
}
```