# WooCommerce Checkout Field html customization issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

In Woocommerce, I'm adding a footnote to a specific checkout field using this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_form_field_text','add_address_disclaimer', 100, 2 );
function add_address_disclaimer( $field, $key ){
    global $woocommerce;    
    if ( is_checkout() && ( $key == 'billing_address_2') ) {
        $field .= '<div class="fields-shipping-disclaimer"><p>' . __('We cannot ship to PO Boxes and FPO/APO addresses.') . '</p></div>';
    }
    return $field;
}
```

It works as it should on init... the footnote displays under the billing address 2 field:

[image]

However, on updating any fields that triggers the "update checkout" option, the custom footnote is not reflected in the refreshed checkout fields:

[image]

Anyone have a clue as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the hook you are using is a **filter hook** not an action hook, so should use `add_filter()` and `global $woocommerce;` is not needed.

Try this code version *(without a div tag)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_text' , 'add_address_disclaimer', 10, 2 );
function add_address_disclaimer( $field, $key) {
    if ( is_checkout() && $key == 'billing_address_2' ) {
        $text   = __("We cannot ship to PO Boxes and FPO/APO addresses.");
        $field .= '<p class="form-row fields-shipping-disclaimer">'.$text.'</p>';
    }
    return $field;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work *(stays on update_checkout JS event)*.

Related thread: [WooCommerce add customs notice below checkout email field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939365/woocommerce-add-customs-notice-below-checkout-email-field/52940382#52940382)

Comment: Quick followup: 

I'm experiencing the same issue with editing field labels: 

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_checkout_fields', 10, 2  );
function override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['label'] = 'Zip / Postal Code';
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']['label'] = 'Zip / Postal Code';

     return $fields;
}
`
I followed that code from the Woo docs... Any thoughts?